getActivitiesByInterval to get Sharepoint usage
I am using below api endpoint for Sharepoint online analytics (site usage):
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/getActivitiesByInterval(startDateTime='2024-05-15',endDateTime='2024-05-19',interval='day')
I am getting data broken down by each day between the date range provided like below:
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.itemActivityStat",
"aggregationInterval": "None",
"startDateTime": "2024-05-15T00:00:00Z",
"endDateTime": "2024-05-21T00:00:00Z",
"isTrending": true,
"access": {
"actionCount": 2463,
"actorCount": 850,
"timeSpentInSeconds": 0
},
"incompleteData": {
"wasThrottled": false,
"resultsPending": false,
"notSupported": false
}
}
actionCount and actorCount are accurate but not sure why timeInSeconds is always showing 0 for each of the day. Any ideas?
I have tried different date ranges and sites but similar result for all.

The lack of hourly granularity is a by-design limitation of the Graph API.
While you can get daily summaries, more granular time intervals (such as hourly breakdowns) are not available directly through the API.

I am not looking for hourly breakdown, I am interested in daily breakdown.
